# guava RangeMap ranges mapped to multiple values

Tags: java, data-structures, guava, range-map

I'm trying to find a data structure such that I will get this:

```
[1, 100) -> A
merge with
[2, 50) -> B
```

will become like this:

```
[1, 2) -> A,
[2, 50) -> A,B
[50, 100) -> b
```

I'm using RangeMap and I want to merge ranges like in the example but it didn't help, I also went through the [docs](https://guava.dev/releases/22.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/RangeMap.html) but didn't find a relevant solution.
Is there a solution within this data structure or is there a better one I can use? thanks!

Comment: Please update your question with some code examples maybe as it's quite unclear for now what you want to do

Comment: Welcome to the community Omri! Please take a look at how to post a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example (minimal reproducible example) in order to help us help you, otherwise, your question is likely to be closed and/or downvoted, which you can avoid by improving it.